# How to get my cursor on a new line after the highlight line of OhMyPosh theme?

Tags: terminal, oh-my-posh

I want the cursor to be on a new line
currently it is on the same line as the highlight line.
I have tried adding `"newline" : true`, but it didn't work.
How can I resolve it ?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty new to Oh My Posh installed on my Mac. I've found very little about what to do to add a `\n` at the end of the prompt in the documentation. I've even tried what I've read in this [dev.to powershell article](https://dev.to/dannyviiprus/improve-window-powershell-promt-with-oh-my-posh-and-more-20md) by adding this block at the end of the json file...

```json
...
    {
      "type": "prompt",
      "alignment": "left",
      "newline": true,
      "segments": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "style": "plain",
          "foreground": "#007ACC",
          "properties": {
            "prefix": "",
            "text": "\uE602"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
...
```

...but it didn't work for me. At best I can only get a `"newline": true` with an empty line between executed commands, e.g.:

```bash
 ~/Downloads  $

 ~/Downloads  $
```

instead of the desired

```bash
 ~/Downloads  
$
 ~/Downloads  
$
```

---

SO!
Even if it might be the less elegant workaround I simply found any `"trailing_diamond": "\ue0b4"` in the omp.json file and (by tries and errors) added to almost all them `\n$`:

```json
...
   "trailing_diamond": "\ue0b4\n$ "
...
```

---

### EDIT:

#### Found a new solution

I stumbled upon a [GitHub Issue comment](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/issues/607#issuecomment-812333646) by JanDeDobbeleer (owner of [JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh)) which is something I'm pretty sure I hadn't found on the documentation, especially in the arguments listed in [Type](https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/configuration/block#type).

Adding a new block with just `type` property and just `newline` as argument works like a the charm :

```
        {
            "type": "newline"
        },
```

---

---

Despite what I thought, **the last approach is now deprecated!**

The solution would still be to use a block (first and last examples) as the last item in the `blocks` array/list

```json
{
  "$schema": ... ,
  ...
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "prompt",
      "alignment": "left",
      "segments": [
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      "alignment": "left",
      "newline": true,
      "segments": [{
        "foreground": "#007ACC",
        "style": "plain",
        "template": "\ue602 ",
        "type": "text"
        }],
      "type": "prompt"
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check first your `#function Prompt()` in your [profile path](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-PowerShell#_update_powershell_prompt).

If it includes, as [shown here](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/355#issuecomment-270664458), $nonewline, then you might have to set `nonewline` to `false`, instead of `newline` to `true`.